# Android app is throwing java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No super method when calling setStateDescription method

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have created a custom view where I want to call `setStateDescription` that is defined in `View` class. But when I call this method app throws following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No super method setStateDescription(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V in class Landroidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout; or its super classes (declaration of 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout' appears in /data/app/com.diginn.diginn.android.app.debug-8lb_baHifl3J_Y9O1Y7TkA==/base.apk)
```

Could you please help me with this.

Comment: [`View#setStateDescription(CharSequence)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setStateDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)) – "Added in API level 30".

Comment: Got it. Thanks for you help. But how can i use this method